# Column name with quotes

Tags: python, pandas

After reading a csv file with read_csv on eof my columns have a name with quotes: "my_col".

I can not access it like:

```
df['"my_col"'] or df['my_col']
```

How could access it? The only thing I can imagine is changing its name. Can I escape the " character?

```
df.columns.tolist()
['\ufeff"COU"',
 'FAM',
  'CHI',
  'ER1',
  'ER2']

"COU","FAM","CHI","ER1","ER2","VAR","EMP","YEA","Unit Code","PowerCodeCode","Reference Period Code","Value","Flag Codes"
"AUS","SGL","0C","0P","NA","SA","EMP","2001",,"0",,9303,
"AUS","SGL","0C","0P","NA","SA","EMP","2002",,"0",,9594,
"AUS","SGL","0C","0P","NA","SA","EMP","2003",,"0",,9883,
"AUS","SGL","0C","0P","NA","SA","EMP","2004",,"0",,10119,
"AUS","SGL","0C","0P","NA","SA","EMP","2005",,"0",,10382,
"AUS","SGL","0C","0P","NA","SA","EMP","2006",,"0",,10676,
 "AUS","SGL","0C","0P","NA","SA","EMP","2007",,"0",,11032,
```

Comment: Can you post sample rows from your csv and also the output from `df.columns.tolist()`

Comment: You can also remove the quotes by doing `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\"','')` or `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\'','')`

Comment: First thing your csv is [utf-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) encoded so pass `encoding='utf-16'` to `read_csv`, secondly you've still not posted a few rows of your csv

Comment: I can read your csv fine using `pd.read_csv(file)` so I don't know what your issue is other than you need to pass `encoding=utf-16'` also to `read_csv`

Comment: @user2082695 Do you want single or double quotes in your column names or do you want no quotes?

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to access a column with quotes in its name or if I have to clean it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the csv file in your case: As suggested by @EdChum in comments, you need to pass `encoding='utf-16`' to `read_csv`

Next part of question: Can you have double quote character (") while referring to a column in dataFrame? The answer is yes. Here is an example:

```
In [7]:

import pandas as pd
d = {
         '"one"': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
         '"two': [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

In [8]:
df['"one"']

Out[8]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
Name: "one", dtype: int64

In [9]:    
df['"two']

Out[9]:
0    9
1    8
2    7
3    6
4    5
Name: "two, dtype: int64
```